# Make my app not available for tablet

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

I'm a newbie with apps (building my first one) and I would like to know how to exclude tablets from my Android manifest and how make to make my app unavailable for download on play store (when using a tablet).

```
<manifest 
 android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="0.2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal"/>
</compatible-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your manifest

```
 <manifest ... >

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>

 <application>

         <!--Rest of the manifest-->
```

Also To identify if it is a tablet with a large screen use this method

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
```

}

Comment: I tried This But it doesn' t work :( it makes my app also downloadable for tablet

Comment: Just done!  The actual manifest make me download my app on tablet, maybe Because i have sw500dp layouts (?)

Comment: Ok,  thank You,  so how can I identify large phone?  (>4')

Comment: I just again added an edit to the code, and you can use that to identify if the device has a large screen

Comment: Yeah,  but i want that users (that use a tablet) can't download  my app on play store

Comment: I have 3 layout for each page,  a normal layout (for small phone)  an h520dp for phone larger,  And a sw500dp for bigger phone. So I need to change This?

Comment: May be try to change that

Comment: And how i can make that?  I want To show different layout for different screen sizes

Comment: you can use size qualifiers like `res/layout/main.xml ` for small devices and `res/layout-large/main.xml` for large devices more information is on http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html